# Laravel websocket beyondco-pusher

Tags: laravel, sockets, websocket, server, pusher

I'm trying to make a socket accessible via api on server side with laravel. But I am getting the following error. I don't understand what am I doing wrong. (i am using
Laravel Framework 8.83.27)

Pusher error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api-.pusher.com

/Api/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmWbT.png)

/Api/config/broadcasting.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgHoM.png)

/Api/config/websockets.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwIpJ.png)

.env
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXfXC.png)

i am getting error in laravel pusher-beyondco library, i am waiting for some idea for solution or solution of this error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)